# Flask-SQLAlchemy: filter by count of relationship objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My models with a one-to-many relationship:

```py
class Entry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "entries"
    ...
    quantities = db.relationship("Quantity", back_populates="entry", lazy="dynamic")

class Quantity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "quantities"
    ...
    entry_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("entries.id"), nullable=True)
    entry = db.relationship("Entry", back_populates="quantities")
```

I have a query like this, works fine to find records where the collection of relationship objects is not empty:

```
# Get entries with not empty quantities
entries = Entry.query.filter(
    Entry.quantities.any()
).all()
```

I also see that I can query to their field values as well:

```py
# Get entries with specific quantities
entries_with_specific_quantities = Entry.query.filter(
    Entry.quantities.any(),
    Entry.quantities.any(Quantity.some_field == "needed_value"),
    ~Entry.quantities.any(Quantity.some_field == "not_needed_value"),
).all()
```

But I can't figure out how can I query for the number of the relationship objects. I tried something like:

```py
# Get entries with specific amount quantities
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

entries_with_specific_amount_of_quantities = Entry.query.filter(
    func.count(Entry.quantities) == 2 # Or any int
).all()
```

Which returns `ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1111, 'Invalid use of group function')`

How can I group the entries and get only the records having the exact amount of relationship objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `any` is compatible with count because it is an aggregate function.

Here is a short solution using `HAVING`.

```py
def entries_with_specific_amount_of_quantities(session, only_count):
    return session.query(
        Entry,
    ).outerjoin(
        Entry.quantities
    ).group_by(
        Entry.id
    ).having(
        func.count(Quantity.id) == only_count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is not flask-sqlalchemy specific, is it? For me a custom function this size seems too much of an overhead, unless it is not do-able with implicit joins of course.

Comment: @MattSom I replaced the prior solution with a shorter solution using `HAVING`.

Comment: Now this is super useful and compact. Thank you very much for the effort!